# issue with pagination when sorting using 'sort_by'

Tags: sorting, ruby-on-rails-4, pagination, will-paginate

I get this error from the [will paginate gem](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate): `undefined method`total_pages' for Array:0xa2710a0`

When I try to paginate in my artist controller after using **'sort_by'** rather 'order'. Does anyone know of a way around this? It seems you can't use paginate in this way because @artists becomes an array rather than an active record collection? Any suggestions are appreciated

to clarify i'm using sort_by rather than .order for these 3 parameters because they're calls to functions within my model, not columns in my Artist database table.

```
def index
    if params[:search]
        @artists = Artist.search(params[:search].titleize).paginate(:page => params[:page]).order("created_at DESC")
    elsif params[:sort] == "numConcerts"
        @artists = Artist.all.paginate(:page => params[:page]).sort_by{|artist| artist.concerts.size}.reverse
    elsif params[:sort] == "avgRating"
        @artists = Artist.all.paginate(:page => params[:page]).sort_by{|artist| artist.avgOverall}.reverse
    elsif params[:sort] == "numReviews"
        @artists = Artist.all.paginate(:page => params[:page]).sort_by{|artist| artist.numReviews}.reverse
    else
        @artists = Artist.paginate(:page => params[:page]).order(:name)
    end
  end
```

the code in the view is just

```
<%= will_paginate @artists %>
```

edit: this seems to be the same issue i'm having, it's from 2008 but i'm going to try: http://pathfindersoftware.com/2008/06/how-to-use-will_paginate-with-non-activerecord-collectionarray/

edit 2: nope couldn't get it to work still

edit 3: tried doing 'require 'will_paginate/array'' but that didn't do fix it.

Comment: Isn't there a way to use `.order` rather than `.sort-by` to get the other sorts you want? For example, `@artists = Artist.order(numReviews: :desc).paginate(:page => params[:page])`

Comment: @lurker i don't think so, because these are calls to functions within my Artist/Concert model, not columns within my database table for Artist.

Answer (score 2):

after much struggling I decided to switch to [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) which works exactly the same but has better integration for handling arrays it seems. I simple did this and it worked.

```
def index
    if params[:search]
        @artists = Artist.search(params[:search].titleize).order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page])
    elsif params[:sort] == "numConcerts"
        @artists = Kaminari.paginate_array(Artist.all.sort_by{|artist| artist.concerts.size}.reverse).page(params[:page]).per(15)
    elsif params[:sort] == "avgRating"
        @artists = Kaminari.paginate_array(Artist.all.sort_by{|artist| artist.avgOverall}.reverse).page(params[:page]).per(15)
    elsif params[:sort] == "numReviews"
        @artists = Kaminari.paginate_array(Artist.all.sort_by{|artist| artist.numReviews}.reverse).page(params[:page]).per(15)
    else
        @artists = Artist.order(:name).page(params[:page])
    end
end
```